# Finding the Regression of a 3D Scatter Plot

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, numerical-methods, regression, data-analysis

I have [a set of 3D Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_bnae3Ly3sM8Hltxca6IMOKe2-vVxC1q-N8tiAk4qlw/edit?usp=sharing), and would like to find an equation that describes the data. The equation will be used to approximate a Z value given an (x,y). I believe that due to the "shape" of the data a non-linear regression will be needed.

I would be very grateful if someone could walk me through this process (I have never taken a stats class). Sorry if this devolves into an "explain like I'm 5" kinda post.